# store number in jquery cookie and delete it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to store a number that is displayed inside a HTML span using jquery cookie.

I add a number to the current value that is displayed inside a span like so:

```
$('.item_count').html(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
```

now I need to store that value in the jquery cookie. so I tried this:

```
    $('.item_count').html(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
    $.cookie("mycookie", $('.item_count').text);
```

I also tried: `$.cookie("mycookie", val);`

but this is not correct and its not storing anything in the cookies.

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: `text` should be `text()`

Comment: `.test()` its a function not a property.

Comment: check your $('.item_count').text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.html()` which you previously used to count value.

```
 $.cookie("mycookie", $('.item_count').html());
```

Instead Of

```
 $.cookie("mycookie", $('.item_count').text);
```

Comment: I'd still opt for using `.text()` (due to no possible interference with contained child tags - even if only for future-proofing). I think the root of the problem is the lack of parentheses, not using the wrong function.